# VS Community 2017 - Creating a Website with Membership/User Login

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to build a very basic ASP.net (VB) site with login/members-only pages, using VS Community 2017.

I found this link and thought I was golden: 
[Walkthrough: Creating a Web Site with Membership and User Login](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx)

However, it's for VS 2010, and a major part of the process is using the "Security setup wizard" which doesn't seem to exist in 2017. Is there some equivalent, or directions for doing the same work in 2017?

Googling with combinations of "Visual Studio 2017" "user login" "membership" "user authentication" etc. has given me mostly results about the VS 2017 software needing a log in, but nothing very helpful about creating a website with login.

Comment: In VS 2017, make a new project, use an ASP.Net Web Application template, and go with MVC; under the security option, choose Local Accounts.  This will scaffold a very basic website with basic user login/management features.  The backend code will be in C# (I don't know if there's a template for these in VB).

if you're just getting started learning ASP.Net, I'd suggest actually focusing on Asp.Net Core, which is the next generation and it is open-source and cross platform. Developing in Asp.Net Core is quite pleasant. There are also lots of tutorials out there for Asp.Net Core now.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) shows the screens I'm referring to. The "Change Authentication" button will lead you to a screen where you can choose "local accounts." Again, this is for asp.net core (this process is the same for Asp.Net), and C#. Once it's scaffolded, you can launch it and see the login/account features.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was hoping there was a way to do it in VB--it's for a hobby project, and I don't have time to learn C# for it, even though that is on my to-do list. I might have to give up on it for now!